# Если в течении t секунд приходит N json запроса с одним и тем же параметром user_id то выполнить такое-то действие

Tags: php

Как реализовать?

Если в течении t секунд приходит N json запросов с одним и тем же параметром user_id то выполнить такое-то действие.

Comment: Что такое json-запрос? И приведите пример вашего кода.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно создать таблицу, которая будет вести статистику по всем запросам. user_id будет одно из полей, которое сохраняется при создании новой записи в истории.
2. Метод, который выполняет json запросы должен при каждом запуске сначала писать в таблицы истории этот ивент, а потом делать выборку для этого user_id и для заданного промежутка времени
3. Исходя из информации полученной из шага 2 уже выполняем нужные действия.

---

В целом если у вас бекэнд для некоего API, то историю запросов все-равно нужно будет вести. Для анализа запросов, для выявления узких мест, для квотирования.

Comment: можно это писать в memory mapped file

Comment: зачем усложнять? если я правильно понял ему нужен 1 endpoint для api и в зависимости от входных уже что-то делать

Comment: @Eugene Nagornichyh извините, а что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Если решение нужно для какой-то мелочи, которая потом никак не разовьется, тогда - можно просто где-то костыликом прикрыть. Но по опыту просто смотрю, что система с развитием требует комплексного решения.

Comment: @Андрей Пиманов а что не понятного?